# Find the First occurrence of Greater then or Less then in 2 different columns

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am looking for Formula in CELL E3, to find the Value such that A:A look for the value >=G3, and C:C to look for the value <=H3, But which ever comes first that value will be entered in E3. 
In our case answer is 483 coz 483 is <=489.5 and it has occurred first.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works for you.

In this example sample data is in Cells A3:C15, solution in E3 and G3 & H3 hold numbers to compare.

Now in E3 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in curly braces automatically to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

```
=IF(MIN(IF(A3:A15-$G$3>=0,ROW(A3:A15)-ROW($B$2),9^99))<=MIN(IF(C3:C15-$H$3<=0,ROW(C3:C15)-ROW($B$2),9^99)),INDEX(A3:A15,MIN(IF(A3:A15-$G$3>=0,ROW(A3:A15)-ROW($B$2),9^99))),INDEX(C3:C15,MIN(IF(C3:C15-$H$3<=0,ROW(C3:C15)-ROW($B$2),9^99))))
```

For this to work in above sample, at least one row should be free above the table. In this case Row 2 is available as our data starts in Row 3. However if your data starts in ROW 1 itself then the `-ROW($B$2)` part in the formula is not required.

Basically it makes a comparison between the columns A , C and G3 , H3 respectively and returns the row number if condition satisfied else a large number in an array. Compare the MIN of two and use INDEX to fetch appropriately either from A or C whichever is smaller.

Note that if you have voluminous data then the Array Formula may slow down due to processing.

In case your regional settings specify semi colon (;) as a list separator rather than comma (,) then you will have to replace commas with semicolons in the formula text.

[image]

Comment: This really works, only if you can edit the formula, to return the value 489.5 or 525.2 as of my example. What I mean, in the comparison iteration suppose in the list the value less then 489.5 occurrs first, so in E3 cell it should not retain actual value 483 but instead return 489.5, and so for the Biggest value